# Android SoftReference To Custom class Containing an AyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, weak-references

I've just started to use SoftReference in my Fragment implementation, which sets setRetainInstance to True, and I have a question concerning..

**Overview:**
What I'm doing is creating a list of soft references in order to be able to have more than one AsyncTask running and still keep references. 
BUT, my list keeps references to custom class objects which wrap an AsyncTask but not one themselves.

**Question:**
Will the behavior of SoftReference stay the same?
Will Android still "couple" my fragment and all those AsyncTask, or am I missing the
whole idea by doing this?

**Code Example:**

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment{
    List<SoftReference<MyClass>> myList;
    ...
}

public class MyClass{
   private AsyncTask task;
   ...
}
```

**Edit:** I changed the question to a SoftReference question after NKN's comment about WeakReference being "too weak". Thx for that..
The question still remains though:)

Comment: Be **very** careful using `WeakReferences` in Android. Keep in mind an app has max. 16MB of memory, so the memory is collected with much more frequence as in common Java frameworks. I'd suggest using minimally `SoftReference`, and always check objects for possible freed instances.

Comment: Thanks! I'm changing to SoftReference right now. I actually knew that and forgot hehe..
Also, I wrap all my "get()" with try & catch for cases the reference is lost..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your idea correctly, you want to have an array of `AsyncTask` instances which you control. In that case, as they probably are enough critical data to store them into that `SoftReference` and endangering their content because of the Garbage Collector, I'd personally change the `SoftReference` approach to get advantage of the `AsyncTask` structure.

I'd declare that `ArrayList` but directly of `MyClass` instances (not `SoftReferences`). You can implement a method in your `MyClass` class like `setTaskId(int)`, and before executing any task, you would call it with, e.g., the index in your `ArrayList` of that instance.

You'd then call the `execute()` method, and once you've terminated processing that `AsyncTask`, the `onPostExecute()` method would be called, from which you'd call a method within your `Fragment` to say this instance of `AsyncTask` has already ended, and you could simply use `yourArrayList.delete(on_that_id)`.

In your question you mention you do this to have several `AsyncTasks`. You may hay as much as you want, but [read this](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/) before doing it because the `execute()` method of `AsyncTask` has suffered drastical changes within version changes and you might need to adequate your code to them.

**--- EDIT ---**

Using `AsyncTask`s within `Fragments` has an additional complication, by the time an `AsyncTask` finished, precisely as you comment, it might have been detached. So you'll have to implement additional logic mechanisms to check whether it is attached via `isDetached()`. Keep also in mind that `isDetached()` only works if you detached your `Fragment` explicitly, otherwise you'll need `isAdded()`.

You don't need to use it all the time, just keep in mind `Fragment` lifecycles and call it whenever you'd need to make an action that involves `Fragment`s being attached and so.

To simplify it a little, you could move the `AsyncTask` initialization and logic to the parent activity, so if a `Fragment` is detached it may act properly (like, e.g., discarding the results if the fragment is no longer attached, or whatever you need).

Comment: Thanks so much for the "read this", helped a lot!

About using direct references, wouldn't it mean that when the fragment will be detached those Async Tasks will not be garbage collected? Because that's why I use SoftReference in the first place... The Tasks jobs isn't that important. Usually a GET request which should be cancelled (and I'm manually canceling) on fragment detach.

    
Also, I've just stumbled upon Google Volley, which should perform better when using connection threads, so I may just move on to use it instead (those tasks should usually load content from the server)

Comment: See my edit, I've added a little explaination on using `AsyncTask`s within `Fragment`s.

Comment: thanks:) I now understand some more about how to use fragments and asyncs.
note that I'm changing my code to use Google Volley when dealing with internet connections, but for the other stuff I'll implement everything.

I'll keep this question unanswered for now if that's ok, just in case someone will want an answer for this in the future (is the reference to the class different from reference to the Async itself)